# How to return UnsafePointer <CChar> and UnsafePointer <CUnsignedInt> with Swift

Tags: c, swift, callback, type-conversion

I'm writing a Swift program that needs to interoperate with a C library.
This C Library consists of a set of functions that use callbacks.
I resolved the problem of how to pass a Swift func to these C functions, but I'm having difficulties to convert Swift native types to the appropriate C types.

Specifically, I have these 2 callbacks (the signature MUST be this in order to be accepted by C library):

```
func peer_name_handler_swift_test(p: peer_wr) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>
{
    return nil;
}

func peer_ver_handler_swift_test(p: peer_wr) -> UnsafePointer<CUnsignedInt>
{
    return nil;
}
```

Well, despite my efforts, I could not return the correct types from String Swift type and from a simple CUnsignedInt array.

The 2 data I would like to return in these callbacks are these one:

```
var BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_VER: [CUnsignedInt] = [0,0,1,0];
var BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_NAME: String = "test_swift_peer";
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Coercing data into the correct pointer types can be done in various ways.  The tricky part to this question is deciding how to manage the memory you are giving out a pointer to.

If you are declaring values known statically at compile time, you could do it like so:

```
// I _think_ you need to manually null-terminate the string here 
let BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_NAME: StaticString = "test_swift_peer\0"

func peer_name_handler_swift_test(p: peer_wr) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>
{
    return UnsafePointer(BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_NAME.utf8Start)
}

// tuples are the closest approximation to C fixed-size arrays
var BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_VER 
         = (0,0,1,0) as (CUnsignedInt,CUnsignedInt,CUnsignedInt,CUnsignedInt)

func peer_ver_handler_swift_test(p: peer_wr) -> UnsafePointer<CUnsignedInt>
{
    return withUnsafePointer(&BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_VER) {
        UnsafePointer($0)
    }
}
```

The extra `UnsafePointer` occurrences in both function bodies are pointer conversion.  In the string case, because `utf8` is `UInt8` but `CChar` is an alias for `Int8`.  In the array case, because you want a pointer to the first `CUnsignedInt` rather than a pointer to a 4-tuple.

If you want to change the values at runtime, you need to decide who’s going to create/free the memory, whether you need to allocate multiple bits of memory because the caller of your callback is going to store the pointer and then if you change it, you are going to need to allocate a new bit of memory rather than overwrite the one you already handed out etc., and if so, how you track that in order to free it later to avoid leaking.  If you want a single static string, but one that you want to create at runtime, say from a config file, you could do this:

```
// prior to the callback getting called
let namePtr = strdup(BLZ_SWIFT_TEST_PEER_NAME)

func peer_name_handler_swift_test(p: peer_wr) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>
{
    return UnsafePointer(namePtr)
}

// then some time later, if you want to clean up
free(namePtr)
```